# Open jquery fancybox on keypress event

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Would anybody know how to open/initiate the lightbox (fancybox) on keypress rather than clicking on a thumbnail? For example, if you hit the space bar the lightbox will open?

I am not that familiar with jquery so please excuse me if the answer seems obvious.

Comment: Sorry, I'm such a novice that I don't even the know syntax for this.

Comment: you really better to know at least basics for javascript events and how jQuery works in browser to be able ask question and understand answer, or rather answers as there is always many ways to do same thing. I would rather trigger click on the fancy box with custom script which would listen key events, but yet there is too small information in question to say something

Comment: ok I understand it maybe too much for me to ask with my skill level. i was hoping there could be a simple line of script I could insert into my head tag to achieve this action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following script to open fancybox pressing the letter "**F**" for instance :

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    // open fancybox pressing "F"
    if (event.keyCode === 70) {
        $.fancybox({
            href: "http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"
        });
    }
}); //keyup
```

... <strike>the issue I see is that you cannot pass the `href` dynamically (as in a link) but you have to hard-code it into the script</strike>*[ See edit ].

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R9nPu/)** (you have to focus on the "result" window before pressing "F")

In order to know what key number is returned for each `keyup`, you could add

```
console.log(event.keyCode);
```

... to the same script (is commented out in my demo)

**NOTE**: this was tested with fancybox v2.1.3

---

**EDIT** (March 11, 2014) :
You could actually bind fancybox to a regular link and trigger a `click` on that element after the *keypress*, so having this html:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="image.jpg">open fancybox</a>
```

You could do :

```
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    // console.log(event.keyCode);
    // open fancybox pressing "F"
    if (event.keyCode === 70) {
        $(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger("click");
    };
}).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

That will fire fancybox either pressing "F" or clicking on the link.

See forked <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/T52aB/1/)</kbd>

Comment: That is fantastic JFK. Thank you. I have got it to work. The keypress activates the one photo: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg. What if you had multiple photos in the lightbox.

Comment: @user1924772 I updated the same demo (pressing F) with multiple photos here http://jsfiddle.net/R9nPu/4/ just remember my comment : you have to hard-code every single `href` for each image.

Comment: Thanks very much. You have been extremely helpful.